# How do I properly format (e.g. Merge Cells) in the "total row" of a matrix?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Observe the following matrix:

[image]

I want to take the last row and make it the grand total in a report.  (That works.)

The problem I have is that I need more real estate to prefix the summation total with descriptive text.  (e.g. *12345 - Field Name - GRAND TOTAL: 55*)

I do not have the ability in the summation row to merge the dynamic columns with the fixed Total Column.

Thus, the only solutions I have come up with are:

1. Increase the total column so that my prefix text will fit
   [image]
2. Move the expression into the merged columns
   [image]

Both of these workarounds produce undesired results.

Is there a way to pretty this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I came up with a third workaround that satisfies requirements.

- The total expression will still go in the total column
- The "prefix" text expression will go in the column before the matrix values
- The row will be highlighted a different color to make it easy to read

[image]